# Where are the brush settings in the Image Editor in Blender 2.80?

Tags: texture-painting, uv-image-editor

Where are the brush settings in the Image Editor? I can't find them anymore:

[image: image editor]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you will have to exit the fullscreen area overlay. Now look over in the *Properties* window. There is a new tab called "*Active Tool and Workspace settings*." This tab will look familiar, and you can find all the same settings you are use to seeing in the tool shelf from pre 2.8.

[image: 2.8 Properties window showing the Active Tool and Workspace settings]