# Blender 3.0 where are the brushes gone? did they remove them

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

installed blender 3.0 like a good boy, but they removed all the brushes.

no, this question doesn't already answer this

[Where are the brush settings in the Image Editor in Blender 2.80?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126759/where-are-the-brush-settings-in-the-image-editor-in-blender-2-80)

[image]

Between the rule of posting every 40 minutes it's total bullshit, since I made this blender account 3 minutes ago and I posted on another forum.

Comment: Hello, what kind of brush would you like to see?

Comment: @moonboots all the default ones: smear, soften, fill, clone, mask

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are available in the *Tool* panel on the left of your 3D view:

[image]

Or in the *N panel > Tool >  Brushes > Image Paint Tool*:

[image]

If you want to create a second *Draw* brush, for example, click on the *Make Single User* button:

[image]